# Select each each row, update it and then move to next row: No Primary Key in Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a situation here and I am bound by my many constraints, so please help me out.

I have a table in my database with 2.5 million rows and no **primary key** because we are going to clean the data in next iteration.

The columns are in this format

```
   [District], [Town Name], [Plant Height]
```

The data in `[Plant Height]` is not in proper format, so I want to iterate through all the rows, pick `[Plant Height]` cell value convert it to some format and then update it. I cannot use the approach to read and then update because update needs a `where` condition and I don't have a primary key in this table and other thing is that I will have to wait for whole night to process these 2.5 million records, so this is not an option.

So, If you can suggest some reliable method in which I can load data and then update it row by row, I will be really thankful

Thank you

Comment: Update does not require where, use that ... also primary key is not required here

Comment: What kind of transformation are you trying to do with `[Plant Height]` column? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Again it is slow. Will Loding all in Datatable help ?

Comment: The units in Plant Height are in different formats like inches,feet,cm,meters etc and I am going to transform them to inches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following steps:

1. Create a temporary or non-temporary table with the same structure as your table but with a primary key (auto-increment).
2. Do the cleanup in the table created in point 1, using the primary key to move through the records.
3. Copy the cleaned up records back to the original table.

Alternatively, you can add the primary key for the cleanup only if you can modify the original table.

Comment: Transfering of 2.5 million records from one table to another and then from there to original will take a lot of time with even SqlBulkCopy

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UPDATE` with `CASE` to apply transformation on one column, without the need of a `WHERE` clause.

Check which format the `[PlantHeight]` column is in and then apply the required transform, an example:

```
UPDATE myTableName  
SET     [PlantHeight] =  
 CASE  
   WHEN [PlantHeight] = <condition> THEN <apply transform cm to inches>
   WHEN [PlantHeight] = <condition> THEN <apply transform m to inches>
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in your table any column or a group of columns with a value that can be used as unique key?  If so, you can do an update using that columns... If not, then tell us what kind of process you have to do with the column.  In other case, I think the suggested temporary table with an identity primary key is a good option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with LINQ to Entities and Entity Framework, you can create a simple console app to accomplish this.  Create an entity data model from your database/table(s).  You would then need to create a loop to do the transformation, and advance a variable with each pass as shown below.  The orderby is required to facilitate the Skip/Take methods which chunks up the processing into 10,000 records per cycle:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        i = QueryRecords(i);
    }

    private static int QueryRecords(int i)
    {
        using (YourEntityModel db = new YourEntityModel())
        {
            var query = (from p in db.Plants
                         select p).OrderBy(x => x.TownName).Skip(i).Take(10000);

            if (query.Count() >= 1)
            {
                ProcessRecords(i, query);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Reached end of records");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    private static void ProcessRecords(int i, IQueryable<Plants> query)
    {
        foreach (Plants item in query)
        {
                //Do your transform
                //    item.PlantHeight = PlantHeight **converted to inches**
                //db.SaveChanges();
        }
        i = i + 10000;
        QueryRecords(i);
    }
}
```